# Does $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}(f-g)(x)=0$ then $f(x)\sim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$ and revert?

Tags: equivalence-relations

- Why does $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}(f-g)(x)=0$ then
  $f(x)\sim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$ false
- and $f(x)\sim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$ implies
  $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}(f-g)(x)=0$ false?

I was given the fact that $f(t)=t \ \& \ f(t)=t^2$ aren't equivalent aroud $0$ but have same limits, but aren't they equivalent as far as they have same limits!

Furthermore I was also given the fact that $f(t)=t \ \& \ g(t)=t+\ln t$ equivalent when $+\infty$ even if their difference is $+\infty$

Comment: What notion of equivalence are you using?

Comment: normally equivalence is not based on difference, but on quotient (at least in the current context of limits) and hence your implications are false in general. By definition $f$ is equivalent to $g$ if $f/g \to 1$. Note that this is not the same thing as $f - g \to 0$. If $g$ is bounded and away from $0$ then both $f - g \to 0$ and $f/g \to 1$ follow from each other. Thus in this particular case both your implications will be true.

Comment: Does the answer to your previous quesiton help or do you have any questions ? Any reaction is appreciated. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754323/solving-a-linear-program-thanks-to-complementary-slackness-theorem/1754537